# Socket io.connect not working even after port is enabled

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My code to connect socket is :

```
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3003', {
                    query: $.param({des: user_info, pic: user_pic})
]  })
```

which is working at local system but on the aws server it's not working as I have enabled the port 3003.

server code --

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
//var find = require('array-find');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3003;
var all = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // not comming here 
});
```

Comment: Will this => `http://localhost:3003` work in your AWS?

Comment: Nope , Not working at  aws , I have tried at aws as
1)  "ws://my-aws-ip:3003"
2)   "http://my-aws-ip:3003"
3)  "http://chat.vertualhost:3003"

But after hitting "npm start" , It comes till 

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

Comment: have you tried "http://you-aws-ip:3003" ?

Comment: Yes tried but works untill ,

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

but could not comes between
io.on('connection', function (socket) {}):